# Modifying owner drawn controls

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, win32gui

I have a third party application I'm writing an add-in for and I need to be able to modify a specific dialog if possible.  That dialog has many controls and groups that are .. it seems, owner drawn and thus don't expose window handles to tools like spy++ and others.  I welcome any insight into how I might disable controls on the this dialog.

Since I am running in-process, I can use detours (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/project/detours/) to intercept functions and use calls like enumwindows/enumchildwindows to find handles to controls that I can then use techniques like NativeWindow (C#) to override wndproc messages and do manipulation.  I'm also familiar with setwindowshookex and hooking the message queues.

Just looking for some ideas and patterns for working with owner drawn controls. Thanks!

[Edit1] I am also familiar with the UI Automation (C#/C++) and IAccessible frameworks.  Those will allow me some control (potentiall), like detecting mouse clicks and such, but I was hoping for something more elegant.  For example: with a normal combobox, if I have a handle, I can use sendmessage() to send it CB_* messages to manipulate its contents.  How do you do that with a combobox if you can't get the handle ... given that it is owner drawn (presumably) and part of another owner drawn parent.

Comment: You won't find anything more elegant than UI Automation.

Comment: Wait, what kind of modifications are you looking to make? Also you probably mean "windowless", not "owner-drawn".

Comment: in an ideal world, I love to be able to call EnableWindow() or send CB_* messages to a combobox

Comment: Which CB_* messages? There are lots of them. Knowing what you want to do will help us determine whether UI Automation can even do what you want to do in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

> thus don't expose window handles to tools like spy++ and others

Then they are not real controls as far as the OS is concerned, and so there is nothing you can do to access/manipulate them *directly*. The app would have to expose an API or UI Automation interface for them.  Presumably the app will not provide more access than it really wants an add-on to have.

You should contact the app author for help fulfilling your goal.